# Received emails from China Company about my Business name and they want to use it

Tags: business-risk, email-spoofing

Email 1:

Dear CEO,

(If you are not the person who is in charge of this, please forward this to your CEO, because this is urgent, Thanks)

We are a Network Service Company which is the domain name registration center in Shanghai, China.
We received an application from Huayu Ltd on April 13, 2015. They want to register " trueblue33 " as their Internet Keyword and " trueblue33 .cn "、" trueblue33 .com.cn " 、" trueblue33 .net.cn "、" trueblue33 .org.cn " domain names etc.., they are in China domain names. But after checking it, we find " trueblue33 " conflicts with your company. In order to deal with this matter better, so we send you email and confirm whether this company is your distributor or business partner in China or not?

Best Regards,

Jim
General Manager
Shanghai Office (Head Office) 
3008, Jiulong Building, No. 836 Nandan Road, 
Xuhui District, Shanghai 200070, China 
Tel: +86 216191 8696 
Mobile: +86 1870199 4951 
Fax: +86 216191 8697
Web: www.cn-registry.net

Email 2:

Dear Sirs,

Our company based in chinese office, our company has submitted the " trueblue33 " as CN(.cn/.com.cn/.net.cn/.org.cn) domain name and Internet Keyword, we are waiting for Mr. Jim's approval. We think this name is very important for our products in Chinese market. Even though Mr. Jim advises us to change another name, we will persist in this name.

Best regards

Jiang zhihai

Email 3:

From: jim.wang@cn-registry.net
To: trueblue33@outlook.com
Subject: CN domain names & Internet Keyword

Dear Anthony Mitchell ,

Based on your company having no relationship with them, we have suggested they should choose another name to avoid this conflict but they insist on this name as CN domain names (cn/ com.cn/ net.cn/ org.cn) and internet keyword on the internet. In our opinion, maybe they do the similar business as your company and register it to promote his company. 
According to the domain name registration principle: The domain names and internet keyword which applied based on the international principle are opened to companies as well as individuals. Any companies or individuals have rights to register any domain name and internet keyword which are unregistered. Because your company haven't registered this name as CN domains and internet keyword on the internet, anyone can obtain them by registration. However, in order to avoid this conflict, the trademark or original name owner has priority to make this registration in our audit period. If your company is the original owner of this name and want to register these CN domain names (cn/ com.cn/ net.cn/ org.cn) and internet keyword to prevent anybody from using them, please inform us. We can send an application form and the price list to you and help you register these within dispute period.

Kind regards

Jim
General Manager
Shanghai Office (Head Office) 
3008, Jiulong Building, No. 836 Nandan Road, 
Xuhui District, Shanghai 200070, China 
Tel: +86 216191 8696 
Mobile: +86 1870199 4951 
Fax: +86 216191 8697
Web: www.cn-registry.net

Comment: is there a question here?

Answer (score 3):

They are selling domain registrations based on what a consumer already owns, adding an implied sense of urgency to make you think you *need* to do this, it is a sales tactic, no more..

I get them all the time, and delete them.